# Exe acts differently when running via remote Azure session vs RDP

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-remoting

We've built an .Net console app that connects to our Windows Service and performs some tasks. If I RDP into an Azure VM and run the command below, it works perfectly:

```
& "$toolDir\my.exe" arg1, arg2 arg3
```

But if I do this via a remote session created by New-PSSession it fails. Here's how I create session. I use this session for many other tasks and everything else (including running MSI, registry, etc) works.

```
$uri = Get-AzureWinRMUri -ServiceName $vmName -Name $vmName
$pwd = convertto-securestring -String $textpwd -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pwd
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $uri[0].DnsSafeHost -Credential $credentials -Port $uri[0].Port -UseSSL -ErrorAction Stop
```

I've tried running my exe in a number of ways in this remote session. I've tried:

1. Invoke-Command -Session $session { ... }
2. Enter-PSSession -Session $session (and typing in the command)
3. Running the commands in different ways, via &, Invoke-Expression, Invoke-Command, Start-Process

The exe always fails to connect to the service. I'm not sure how relevant the error is, but here is the exception (and inner exception) reported:

```
There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/myservice that could 
accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 

The pipe name could not be obtained for net.pipe://localhost/myservice .
```

Again, this works perfectly when run in powershell on box via RDP. So I thought it might be because of lack of $profile, so I ran inside a new powershell created on RDP using CMD:

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File C:\test.ps1
```

But that worked too.

Both RDP and remote session use the same credentials. What differences are there between a remote session and using powershell inside RDP that could cause this?

UPDATE: Also tried putting the exe call into a batch file on the server, and then called that batch file - still same error.  Everything still points to a difference between the remote session and the RDP session.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session {
    cd c:\mytools
    cmd.exe /c runmyexe.bat 
}
```

WORKAROUND: I could not figure out how to find differences between sessions, so I took advantage of a reboot that was already part of my setup script. I wrote out a bat file and put into startup folder, rebooted then deleted it, all automatically. It works great. Still a little worrying that the sessions are different somehow..

Comment: Does your exe use any kind of impersonation inside?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. searching the code now

Comment: Can you post some code pf the my.exe showing how you are connecting?  That error message sounds like it is using named pipes.  I don't have any experience with Azure's Remote Sessions to know if named pipes will work or not; instead, I usually code in Azure for TCP connections - that way I don't have to initiate a remote session.  But even if you were using a remote session, "net.pipe://localhost/myservice" doesn't sound like you are talking to the remote VM.

Comment: Thanks Eric, the issue was 'resolved' by using PsExec -s in the end. In other words, I stopped looking for the root cause and found a workaround ;)